# how to convert photoshop animated image to html

Tags: photoshop

I have a PhotoShop image with a few layers. The image is animated. I was wondering if there is a way to convert or export it into html and keep the animation. I have the latest version of Photoshop

Comment: Is this a coding question? Or do you want to export your psd as animated gif/sequence of images?

Comment: trying to export psd as animated but in html format